# Setting up a Japanese Windows OS

Tags: windows, regional-settings, language-pack

One of our functional requirements at work require running a piece of software over a Japanese environment --- which means we'll have to set up a Japanese flavor of Windows for the job.

Question is, can we just patch our Windows Vista/7 with Japanese MUI language packs for this? Are there any significant functionality differences between the English and Japanese versions of Vista/7 that forces us to perform a clean install of a Japanese Windows OS instead of just patching an English one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as simple as downloading additional MUIs, the easiest way is to install them as optional updates from Windows Update.

However, a limitation is that additional language packs are only available on Enterprise and Ultimate editions.

As for downsides, the only one I can think of is that you may have to learn Japanese!

Comment: Haha, understanding Japanese is no problem at all, but yeah, we definitely should put that in writing somewhere :D So basically, the English and Japanese versions of Vista/7 function the same? No hidden kinks here, no GOTCHA quirks there?

Comment: The MUI packs simply change text and language features, the actual OS fundamentals are the same. I have never used Japanese, but can't imagine any problems what so ever.

Comment: As far I am aware this is 100% correct - it's all in the MUI.